# How to overwrite language labels in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, rte

I'd like to change language labels used in TinyMCE. E.g. "Überschrift 2" -> "Überschrift".

Im using the jQuery plugins version of TinyMCE.

Is there a way to overwrite those labels without editing the label files?

Answer (score 2):

Just found this question and I did it in the following way (using tinyMCE 4.1.x):

```
tinymce.init({
          language : 'en_GB',
          init_instance_callback : function(editor) {
              tinymce.i18n.data.en_GB['New window'] = 'Open in new tab or window';
              tinymce.i18n.data.en_GB.Target = 'Options';
          }
      });
```

What this does is override the defaults with your text after the editor has been initialised. No need to edit any lang files

Comment: This is for sure the best answer without doing any source modifications

Comment: Add: You can even define new custom labels like this for own used title labels.

Answer (score 1):

yeah look for the 'langs' folder edit de.js.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do that without editing the source files?
I'd like to insert that into the script where I create the tinymce instances.

Comment: i'm sure you could find a workaround and somehow edit the variables. But you cant just give them as params on the init. Best way is to edit the lng file. Make a custom one if you don't want to edit the standart file.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. 
I've tested it at least for my own localization strings, using helpers *geti18nstring()* and *set18nstring()* handling tinymce.i18n property.

BTW, Here is the 'full' documentation http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:property.tinymce.i18n of property. :) 
The rest of snippet is done using well-known agile pattern 'trust-the-source-Luke'.

```
// folder: plugins/mycustomtinymceplugin
//
// file: ./langs/en_dlg.js

tinyMCE.addI18n('en.mycustomtinymceplugin_dlg',{charts:"Some charts"});

// file: mycustomtinymceplugin.html <-- opened by ./editor_plugin.js#init ed.windowManager.open({file : url + '/mycustomtinymceplugin.html'
<script>

function geti18nstring( id )
{
    return tinymce.i18n[ tinymce.activeEditor.settings.language + '.mycustomtinymceplugin_dlg.' + id ];
}
function seti18nstring( id, i18nstring )
{
    //just for curiosity if you wan't to modify something in a plugin which is killed after modification
    if( geti18nString( id ) == i18nstring )
    {
    alert( 'id['+id+'] was replaced already with [' + i18nstring +'].' );
    }
    else
    {
    tinymce.i18n[ tinymce.activeEditor.settings.language + '.mycustomtinymceplugin_dlg.' + id ] = i18nstring;
    }
}

function dostuffonpluginstart()
{
    //to get localized strings
    var charts_text = geti18nstring('charts');
    $('#chartlist').append( charts_text );
    ...
    //to manipulate localized strings
    seti18nstring( 'charts', 'karamba' );
    charts_text = geti18nstring('charts');
    $('#chartlist').append( charts_text )
}
</script>
...

<div id"chartlist"></div>
```